# Unable to perform mocking setup

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I am trying to make use of nunit together with to do unit testing. However I am experiencing this error:

> Moq.MockException: The following setups were not matched:
>   `User m => m.encrptPassword(It.IsAny<String>(), It.IsAny<String>())`

The following is the snippet of my code that is having issues:

```
private User _User;
Mock<User> mockUser;

[SetUp]
public void init()
{
    mockUser = new Mock<User>();
    _User = new User();
}

[Test]
[TestCase("1","admin","??????_????k0O???qr#??%szq??` ?j???????D>?????????Lvz??BP")]
public void encryptPasswordTest(string userID, string password, string output)
{

    mockUser.Setup(m => m.encryptPassword(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(() => output);
    string result = _User.encryptPassword(userID, password);
    Assert.That(result.Equals(output));

    mockUser.VerifyAll();
}
```

The following is the method that I am trying to mock

```
public virtual string encryptPassword(string userID, string password) {
    string hashed = "";
    HashAlgorithm sha256 = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();
    string salted = userID + password;
    byte[] result = sha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(salted));
    hashed = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(result);
    return hashed;
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @AlexRiabov I would like to perform a test to see the parameters I provided, would be the same output when it runs the actual method from the actual class and mock class

Comment: @Nkosi mockUser is just Mock<User>, while _User is a class that contains the method that I want to test

Comment: This turns out to be 
an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). There is no need for a mock in this case. Just exercise the subject under test and assert the behavior. Right now it looks like you are trying to test the mocking framework and not your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any mocking in your case, you just have to check functions output:

```
[Test]
[TestCase("1","admin","??????_????k0O???qr#??%szq??` ?j???????D>?????????Lvz??BP")]
public void encryptPasswordTest(string userID, string password, string output)
{ 
    string result = _User.encryptPassword(userID, password);
    Assert.That(result.Equals(output));
}
```

You would need mocking if you'd need to validate your logic depending on output of another component. E.g. you have

```
public interface IEncrypter
{
    string encryptPassword(string userID, string password);
}
```

and inject it to User class:

```
public User(IEncrypter encrypter) { this.encrypter = encrypter; }
```

Then you would mock it:

```
var mock = new Mock<IEncrypter>();
mock.Setup(m => m.encryptPassword(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(() => output);
var user = new User(mock.Object);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. Pardon me as I just picked up mock in just a few days.